# convert Date to a quarter of an hour type JAVA

Tags: java, date, casting

I am looking for a way to convert the datatype DATE [JAVA]

to a quarter of an hour format, so that

> 2010-08-15 12:05:15 will be  2010-08-15 12:00:00

Are there any ready to go methods in JAVA already?

How would you do this?

Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at the `joda-time` library?

Comment: you can do stuffs with `java.util.Calendar` class, but I couldn't understand what is `quarter of an hour format`? More input and output may help?

Comment: @sanbhat 12:05:15 will be rounded to 12:00:00 12:27 will be rounded to 12:30 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to release version 7, Java comes with a terrible date and time API. Many developers therefore choose to use [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead. It is a very common third-party dependency in many projects.

Using Joda time, you can do the following:

```
 Date toQuaterOfHour(Date date) {
   LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime(date.getTime());
   int quater = ldt.getMinuteOfHour() / 15;
   return ldt.withMinuteOfHour(quater * 15).toDate();
 }
```

Java 8 comes with a [date and time API](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) that is similar to that of Joda time.

Comment: Basically. The migration should be rather easy due to the similarity of the APIs. Package-wise, Joda time and the new Java time API live in different name spaces. Also, some of the methods have different names as visible from: http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html - An example would be the method `withMinute` instead of `withMinuteOfHour`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Calendar object, then you can and manipulate the indvidual fields

```
  int min = cal.get (Calendar.MINUTE);

  int val = min / 15;  // or what ever logic you have.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, joda-time is battle tested well known solution for working with date/times in Java, so if you can push it into your project, do it (or at least try).

Second, I can help you with that, but please put here fully qualified name of object you are using. Date in java.util is mostly deprecated, so I would suggest looking on GregorianCalendar object (included in JDK) for date/time manipulation.

Comment: I think this is just a comment.

Comment: You're right, next-time I provide sample code as well :)

Comment: But what is deprecated in java.util.Date has been deprecated since 1.1

Comment: and ? I state otherwise ?

Comment: Just adding a comment to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You may use simple arithmetic like this:

```
long millis = 15 * 60 * 1000;
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long rest = now % millis;
long quarter = now + (rest == 0 ? 0 : rest >= millis / 2 ? millis - rest : -rest);

System.out.println("Original: " + new Date(now));
System.out.println("Quarter: " + new Date(quarter));
```

Use the class SimpleDateFormat and choose the output format of your choice.